# Mysql count group by reverse

Tags: mysql, count, group-by

I understand about how to use the count with the group by, but I need a specific use of this reverse, I try to do this query:

```
SELECT
        COUNT(pac.strid_paciente)
    FROM tb_paciente AS pac
    LEFT JOIN tb_entidades AS ent
        ON pac.strid_entidad = ent.strid_entidad
    LEFT JOIN tb_escolaridad AS esc
        ON pac.strid_escolaridad = esc.strID_Escolaridad
    LEFT JOIN tb_etnia AS etn
        ON pac.strid_etnia = etn.strID_Etnia
    LEFT JOIN tb_raza AS raza
        ON pac.strid_raza = raza.strid_raza
    LEFT JOIN tb_religion AS rel
        ON pac.strid_religion = rel.strid_religion
    LEFT JOIN tb_ocupacion AS ocu
        ON pac.strOfi_Paciente = ocu.strID_Ocupacion
    LEFT JOIN tb_consulta AS con
        ON pac.strid_paciente = con.strid_paciente
    LEFT JOIN tb_usuarios AS usu
        ON usu.strid_usuario = con.strid_medico
    GROUP BY pac.strid_paciente
```

And it gives me:

```
COUNT(pac.strid_paciente)
1
1
2
3
4
5
2
```

I need the result of every count: 18, the problem is that I cant delete the group by because give a different result. Something like that:

```
   COUNT(pac.strid_paciente)
   18
```

Comment: Not clear what you're asking...

Comment: Why do you need the group by if you just return the count? I agree with @Sebas

Comment: I need the group by because without it the `SELECT` return me more rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried `SUM( COUNT(pac.strid_paciente) )` OR if that fails then the following will work:

```
SELECT SUM( t.cnt ) FROM(
SELECT
    COUNT(pac.strid_paciente) AS cnt
FROM tb_paciente AS pac
LEFT JOIN tb_entidades AS ent
    ON pac.strid_entidad = ent.strid_entidad
LEFT JOIN tb_escolaridad AS esc
    ON pac.strid_escolaridad = esc.strID_Escolaridad
LEFT JOIN tb_etnia AS etn
    ON pac.strid_etnia = etn.strID_Etnia
LEFT JOIN tb_raza AS raza
    ON pac.strid_raza = raza.strid_raza
LEFT JOIN tb_religion AS rel
    ON pac.strid_religion = rel.strid_religion
LEFT JOIN tb_ocupacion AS ocu
    ON pac.strOfi_Paciente = ocu.strID_Ocupacion
LEFT JOIN tb_consulta AS con
    ON pac.strid_paciente = con.strid_paciente
LEFT JOIN tb_usuarios AS usu
    ON usu.strid_usuario = con.strid_medico
GROUP BY pac.strid_paciente
) AS t
```